# PHP CSV create and force download

Tags: php

This is for csv file create and force download for that file.

This working but I need to know is it doing correct way.

public function exportCSV($results){

```
    try {

        $filename = CSV_PATH.'file.csv';

        $numRows = count($results);

        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')  or die("can't open file");

        fputcsv($handle, array('id','name','age','address'));

        foreach ($results as $row) {

            fputcsv($handle, $row);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($filename);
        exit();

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

CSV_PATH is on config.php file

Comment: Personally I'd use a tempfile rather than a file with a fixed name... that way you won't have any problems if two different users request a csv download at the same time; and it you can delete the file on disk after it has been sent to the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
   use  string rather then file writing it causes lot of overhead. 
   $out = "";
   $out .= implode(",", array('id','name','age','address')) . "\r\n";

   foreach ($results as $row) {
       $out .= implode(",", $row) . "\r\n";
    }
```

now do same .

```
....
header('Connection: close');
echo $out;
```

Comment: Why recommend manually creating each line when the fputcsv() function handles a lot of potential data problems that your code doesn't (e.g a comma in the address field)

Comment: And please do tell, how can the OP set content-length header when there's no file to get the `filesize`? How are you dealing with data that looks like this: _"My Address 123, Zip"_ <--- the `,` is the CSV delimiter, too. `fputcsv` will enclose this data using quotes, your approach doesn't do this...